# How to start by pass reference in debug

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Hye guys,in this programme i want the user to set the cam recording frame rate and desired project frame rate to get actual frame rate.(i know it sounds ridiculous im sorry) so i use by pass reference.The program build succeed but the void get data doesnt get initiate when i debug manually.how could this happen and how to fix this? it is on line 123 i cant get further with debugging

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void manualMode();
void defaultMode();
void Getdata(double& camrecord, double& projectfps);
void calculate(double& camrecord, double& projectfps, double& actual);
void Displayactualframerate(double& out);



int speed, timeTofly, operation;
int angle = 90;

int main() {
    int mode = 0, part = 3;
    double flyLevel;
    int obstacleSensor = 0, timer = 3, AccelerometerSensor = 0, tempSensor = 25;
    char startPause;
    cout << "Drone Flying Technology" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Choose Mode: (1)Default, (2)Manual \n";
        cin >> mode;
        if (mode == 1)
            defaultMode();
        if (mode == 2)
            manualMode();
    } while (mode == 0);

    cout << "Choose how to fly: (1)Upper , (2)Lower , (3)Upper and Lower \n";
    cin >> part;
    switch (part) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        flyLevel = 0.5;
        break;
    case 3:
        flyLevel = 1;
        break;
    }
    if (obstacleSensor == 0) {
        do {
            cout << "Press (S) to Start,and swing the propeller." << endl;
            cin >> startPause;
            cout << "LED is On\n";
            while (AccelerometerSensor != flyLevel) {
                AccelerometerSensor++;
            }
            cout << "Flying session Started! Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
            cout << "Eagle eye Operation Started!\n";
            timeTofly = timeTofly / 2;
            cout << "Crusing mode initiate Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
            timeTofly = timeTofly / 2;
            cout << "Free fly commenced Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
            timeTofly = 0;
            startPause = 'P';
        } while ((startPause == 's') || (startPause == 'S'));
    }
    cout << "End!\nLED is Off";
    return 0;
}


void manualMode() {
    cout << "Enter drone speed (knot) \n";
    cin >> speed;
    cout << "Enter Time to fly: \n";
    cin >> timeTofly;
    cout << "Choose Operation: (1)Fully manual, (2)Normal Orientation, (3)Free orientation, (4)FPV racing, (5)All\n";
    cin >> operation;
}
void defaultMode() {
    int howtofly;
    cout << "how to fly: (1)Circle, (2)Altitude Hold, (3)Free orientation\n";
    cin >> howtofly;
    switch (howtofly) {
    case 1:
        speed = 30;
        timeTofly = 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        speed = 40;
        timeTofly = 3;
        break;
    case 3:
        speed = 60;
        timeTofly = 3;
        break;
    }


    char name[25];
    char id[5];
    float m1, m2, m3, m4, m5;

    ofstream outputFile("droneinfo.txt", ios::out);

    cout << "Please enter object you want to record,drone id imei number and your 5 preferred video fps:\n";
    cout << "\nPress <ctrl> + z to stop. \n";

    while (cin >> id >> name >> m1 >> m2 >> m3 >> m4 >> m5)
    {
        outputFile << id << " " << name << " " << m1 << " " << m2 << " " << m3 << " " << m4 << " " << m5;
    }

    double camrecord;
    double projectfps;
    double actual, out;


    Getdata(camrecord, projectfps);
    calculate(camrecord, projectfps, actual);
    Displayactualframerate(actual);



}
void Getdata(double& camrecord, double& projectfps) {
    cin >> camrecord;
    cin >> projectfps;

    cout << "Please enter cam recording =" << camrecord << "f/s ,\nDesired footage frame rate="
        << projectfps<<"f/s";
}


//-------------------//
void calculate(double& camrecord, double& projectfps, double& actual) {
    actual = (camrecord / projectfps);
}


//-------------------//
void Displayactualframerate(double& out) {

    cout << "\nThe actualframerate is =" << out << " f/s\n";

   
}
```

Comment: Once the user presses Ctrl+Z to stop (as the program prompts them to), `cin` is marked as having reached end-of-file. No further input can be read from it. `cin >> camrecord` and `cin >> projectfps` in `Getdata` fail without reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are stuck in the while(cin >> ...) loop? Because I am while trying to replicate your problem.

Removing it works:

```
    cin >> id >> name >> m1 >> m2 >> m3 >> m4 >> m5;
    
    outputFile << id << " " << name << " " << m1 << " " << m2 << " " << m3 << " " << m4 << " " << m5;
```

Comment: yes i do stuck at that i cant seem to continue to void get data

Comment: Why do you use this loop at all? What is it's purpose?

Comment: I'm just trying and learning to do fstream output file mode while doing loop
i know that can just do as simple as this which i got no problem debug

    cin >> id >> object >> m1 >> m2 >> m3 >> m4 >> m5;
    
        outputFile << id << " " << object << " " << m1 << " " << m2 << " " << m3 << " " << m4 << " " << m5<<endl;